# How to render a React component when its ID is known only after an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I am working on a chat application which renders a chat message (a React component) as soon as the user sends it by pressing `Enter`:

[image]

[image]

Here, after typing `ABC` and pressing `Enter`, the React component's state is updated right-away and the message is rendered in order to avoid a sluggish UI.

Then an AJAX request is made. The AJAX sends the message to the server, which in turn, creates a new chat if `chat_id` is 0 (first message of the chat), saves the message and returns the ID of the newly created chat.
At this point the chat is updated with the ID returned by the server. Below a snippet of the code:

```
class ChatApp extends React.Component {

    // ...
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            currentChat: {
                id: 0, // 0 means "this is a new chat"
                messages: [],
                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    handleSendMessage(message) {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            const pendingCurrentChat = {
                ...prevState.currentChat,
                messages: prevState.currentChat.messages.concat([{
                    message
                }])
            }
            return {
                currentChat: pendingCurrentChat
            }
        }, () =>
            this.setState((state) => {
                const currentChat = state.currentChat
                const currentChatId = currentChat.id

                // AJAX call starts here:
                const params = {
                    act: 'handleSendMessage',
                    message: message,
                    chat_id: currentChatId
                }
                this.POST(params, JSONResponseData =>
                    this.setState((prevState) => {
                        const chatId = JSONResponseData.chat_id

                        const currentChat = {
                            ...prevState.currentChat,
                            id: chatId
                        }
                        const newState = {
                            currentChat
                        }
                        return newState
                    })
                )

                // No state change here.
                return null
            })
        )
    }

    // ...

}
```

The problem of this approach is that, if the chat is new (`currentChat.id == 0`), and the user sends a bunch of messages by typing and pressing `Enter` rapidly, a race condition occurs and some AJAX requests with `chat_id: 0` overlap leading to multiple chats being created server-side:

[image]

Here, I have typed `a` and Enter rapidly and I ended up with more than one chat being created server side, because several requests were made with `chat_id` set to `0`.

How can I assure that only the first message of the chat is sent to the server with `chat_id: 0` without experiencing a race condition if the user types in a fast way?

I can only think of:

- Generating IDs on the client side (perhaps a UUID), which is then sent to the server. I really do not want to let the user wait until the first AJAX completes before rendering the first message;
- Create a new chat before letting the user to send a message. Though, this way I will consume IDs on the server even when a user might not send a first message;

Facebook's Messenger for example has the behaviour I am looking for: when you send a message it is rendered as soon as you press `Enter`, how do they handle this? By looking at the network tab, it seems that they create an ID in advance, but I am not sure:

[image]

How would you handle this both in terms of UI/UX and server-side data persistence?

Comment: I'd generate a chat UUID serverside, stick it in the session, then provide it to the page when mounting the React component. Then, the React component can just use the chat ID it's given. This would have the benefit of letting a user preserve their same chat session over multiple tabs or pageviews. Messages themselves should have serial numbers, but shouldn't be used to indicate the chat session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generate an id client-side that persist until the fetch response is solved.

And then, if the client id is the same that just created a new chat, don't create new chats, store the new messages somewhere until you have your fresh server id, and push them online.

Comment: But, how would you handle the race condition when typing the message and `Enter` fast? It could happen that multiple AJAX requests will overlap and you will send the same client generated ID to the server more than once? Would you store the client ID on the server too for lookup in case of overlapping requests?

Comment: You should consider using underscore debounce. Wait and send only one request every few seconds depending on your use case. https://underscorejs.org/#debounce

Comment: @user642206 Could you provide an example in your answer, please?

Comment: So the idea would be to use the second option you where thinking about. You will wait till the user sends a message. debounce this message so you only make one ajax request in a period of time. use the return from that ajax to create the chat room. and subsequent messages will be added to that room. Because you are using debounce there will be no race and you are sure the first request will be completed before subsequent request gets made. I am not at home, so i cant write out an example. just my initial thoughts

Comment: @tonix Why not control for that client generated id to NOT trigger more AJAX calls until the first one is resolved?

Comment: @JosepVidal Yes, I will try to do what you suggest.

Comment: @JosepVidal `Why not control for that client generated id to NOT trigger more AJAX calls until the first one is resolved?` Tried what you suggested and it worked. Thanks!